I can't understand this Se
"Encontré un pétalo de rosa y se la puse debajo de su almohada."
Why Is it "se la puse"? I don't see any indirect object, it's not passive voice, the verb isn't reflexive, and it doesn't seem to warrant any emphasis. These situations have been confusing me, there's a lot of "se"'s where I can't understand why they're used.

I'm curious about the word "su" in "su almohada".  It sounds like the pillowbelongs to a person.  Perhaps "se"mrefers to the same person.  Maybe you could add some of the context surrounding the quote.

We can have these variants:

Encontré un pétalo de rosa y lo ("pétalo" is masculine) puse debajo de la almohada. (No reference to under whose pillow and in whose interest the petal was placed there)

Encontré un pétalo de rosa y lo puse debajo de su almohada. (It is clear that the petal was placed under somebody else's pillow)

Encontré un pétalo de rosa y se lo puse debajo de la almohada. ("se" is a dative. It can indicate possession, in which case it is similar to (2) -- the pillow was his/hers -- or it can indicate benefit -- I put it under some pillow for his/her benefit)

Encontré un pétalo de rosa y se lo puse debajo de su almohada. (In the presence of possessive "su", "se" is a dative of interest reinforcing the idea that the petal was placed under his/her pillow for his/her own benefit)



Se
Verbo: 1era persona, presente verbo Saber modo indicativo “no se de que hablas”
Verbo: 2da persona modo imperativo “se tu mismo”
“Passive voice” voz pasiva, existe debate acerca de su existencia en español, eso es más anglosajón que latino (por latino hago referencia a las lenguas derivadas del latín)
El único énfasis es quizás que el pétalo per se no llegó por sí mismo debajo de la almohada.
Editado: ya tuve tiempo y aquí está la definición que marca la RAE.
se
Palabra átona invariable, que debe escribirse sin tilde, a diferencia de la forma tónica sé, que corresponde a la primera persona del singular del presente de indicativo de saber y a la segunda persona del singular del imperativo de ser (→ tilde2, 3). Hay que distinguir entre los usos pronominales de se (→ 1) y su empleo como indicador de oraciones impersonales y de pasiva refleja (→ 2):

Se pronominal

Como pronombre personal, invariable en género y número, tiene distintos valores:
a) Variante formal de le(s). Cuando el pronombre de dativo le(s) precede a alguno de los pronombres de acusativo de tercera persona lo(s), la(s), adopta la forma se: Les compré caramelos > Se los compré; Le puse los zapatos > Se los puse. En cuanto a la transferencia del rasgo plural del dativo invariable se al pronombre de acusativo que le sigue (Les di un premio > Se los di), → pronombres personales átonos, 6.b. Solo en casos esporádicos se es variante formal de los pronombres de acusativo lo(s), la(s), como en Llaman cobarde a María > La llaman cobarde > Se lo llaman; o en Oí a las niñas cantar la canción > Las oí cantar la canción > Se la oí cantar.
